# which vector to be conjugate transposed in the Gram-Schmidt process

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gram-schmidt

I got to use the Gram-Schmidt process to find an orthonormal basis for M3x3($\mathbb{C}$). The Gram-Schmidt process is consisted of two steps: normalization of each vector and subtraction of its projection on others (left ones).
When doing the projection, which vector should be transpose conjugated?

$u_{i} = v_i - \langle\cdot u_1,v_i \rangle\cdot u_1 - \langle\cdot u_2,v_i \rangle\cdot u_2 - ... - \langle\cdot u_{i-1},v_i \rangle\cdot u_{i-1}$

$u_{i} = \dfrac{u_i}{\mid u_i \mid}$

For complex vectors, I don't know which component ($u$ or $v$?) should be transpose conjugate. It seems that either way works and generates a different orthonormal basis.

For example, a 3x3($\mathbb{C}$) matrix A,

$A = \begin{bmatrix}  1 &   2  &    4\\
                      1 & 4-i  & 8+2i\\
                      2 &   3  &    6\end{bmatrix}$

with conjugate transpose on $u$ (the destination of the projection), I got

$Q_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0.41  &       0.07i & 0.34-0.85i\\
                     0.41  &  0.83-0.35i &      0.17i\\
                     0.82  & -0.41+0.14i & -0.17+0.34i\end{bmatrix}$

with conjugate transpose on $v$ (the projected vector), I got

$Q_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0.41  &      -0.07i & 0.03+0.07i\\
                     0.41  &  0.78-0.46i & 0.47+0.87i\\
                     0.82  & -0.39-0.13i & -0.07+0.03i\end{bmatrix}$

Either one generates a upper triangle matrix by computing $Q^{-1} A$.

Conjugate transpose on u seems to generate a unitary matrix. $Q_1^* Q_1 = I$ but $Q_2^* Q_2 \neq I$

Which is the correct Gram-Schmidt process?

I think conjugate transpose on u is correct because the other way doesn't create an orthogonal vector to $u$. For example, let a and b two complex 2 dimensional vectors.

$a = \begin{bmatrix}1+2i\\3+5i\end{bmatrix}$

$b = \begin{bmatrix}4-6i\\2+1i\end{bmatrix}$

The following vector is orthogonal to $a$

$b - \dfrac{\langle a^*,b \rangle}{\langle a^*,a \rangle} a = \begin{bmatrix}2.85-5.62i\\-0.92+2.23i\end{bmatrix}$

but the following vector is NOT orthogonal to $a$.

$b - \dfrac{\langle b^*,a \rangle}{\langle a^*,a \rangle} a = \begin{bmatrix}5-6.69i\\4.46-i\end{bmatrix}$

So if you want to project $\vec{b}$ onto vector $\vec{a}$,

$\dfrac{\langle a^*,b \rangle}{\langle a^*,a \rangle} a$

is the correct one (the destination vector needs to be conjugated). I don't know why the other way doesn't work...